# How to make sshfs (from windows) use chmod 644 instead of 700 as default?

Tags: windows, remote-access, sshfs

I'm using sshfs-win to connect windows explorer to linux box over ssh.

All good but new files are 700 instead of default 644.

```
rwx------ < bad
rw-r--r-- < default
```

sending a file over psftp also uses (the prefered) 644. 
Is there any setting where I can change this behaviour?

ATB

Comment: Does that application provide you with an option to  set and `umask` and/or `create_umask`   or similar option ?

Comment: Thanks, not too familiar with the underlying FUSE, found similar post at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290212/understanding-sshfs-and-umask

Comment: Seems to be a common issue: https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp/issues/138